# no implicit conversion of Hash into String Couldn't create 'API_development' database. Please check your configuration. rails aborted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-6

when I try to create database I get below errors:

[image]

Command `rails db:create --trace` gives below:

```
no implicit conversion of Hash into String
Couldn't create 'API_development' database. Please check your configuration.
rails aborted!
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Hash into String
/mnt/c/Users/Jaydip/Documents/project/API/bin/rails:5:in `<top (required)>'
/mnt/c/Users/Jaydip/Documents/project/API/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
/mnt/c/Users/Jaydip/Documents/project/API/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:create
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
jaydip@DESKTOP-AD7S893:/mnt/c/Users/Jaydip/Documents/project/API$ rails db:create --trace
** Invoke db:create (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:create
no implicit conversion of Hash into String
Couldn't create 'API_development' database. Please check your configuration.
rails aborted!
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Hash into String
/home/jaydip/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@API/gems/mysql2-0.5.0/lib/mysql2/error.rb:55:in `encode'
/home/jaydip/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@API/gems/mysql2-0.5.0/lib/mysql2/error.rb:55:in `initialize'
/home/jaydip/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@API/gems/mysql2-0.5.0/lib/mysql2/error.rb:62:in `new'
/home/jaydip/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@API/gems/mysql2-0.5.0/lib/mysql2/error.rb:62:in `new_with_args'
/home/jaydip/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@API/gems/mysql2-0.5.0/lib/mysql2/client.rb:90:in `connect'
/home/jaydip/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@API/gems/mysql2-0.5.0/lib/mysql2/client.rb:90:in `initialize'
/home/jaydip/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@API/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:40:in `new'
...
Tasks: TOP => db:create
```

Note: I am using WSL linux subsystem of windows.

Can anyone please help to resolve it ...

Update: Here is image of database.yml file
[image]

Solution : I changed mysql2 gem version 0.5.0 to 0.5.3 and error was gone.

Comment: No need for the entire error trace - you can probably shorten it. It is most likely a problem with your `database.yml` - can you post the most minimal version of it?

Comment: I have added database.yml image